# Promoting a specific OctopusDeploy release in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am using [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for continuous integration and [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) for continuous deployment.

In TeamCity, I have a project which I build and then package using Octopus Deploy's [OctoPack](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack). There are currently three build configurations defined:

1. Build, Test, Package
2. Deploy to CI
3. Deploy to QA

For the OctoPack configuration in the first configuration, the package version is generated via the build number:

```
OctoPack package version: 1.0.0.%build.number%
```

The deploy to CI then initiates an Octopus Deploy release if `Build, Test, Package` successfully builds. Octopus Deploy uses the NuGet version number as the release version number when the release is created. So for build #400 I have a `My.Project.1.0.0.400.nupkg` NuGet package, which is released as version `1.0.0.400`.

in the `Deploy to QA` step, I need to be able to promote the release associated with a specific `Deploy to CI` build from my `CI` environment to my `QA` environment.

In essence, I want to be able to have this kind of dependency tree:

```
Build, Test, Package
|-- #401 SUCCESS
|-- #400 FAILURE
|-- #399 FAILURE
|-- #398 SUCCESS
/   #391-397 FAILURE
|-- #390 SUCCESS

Deploy to CI
|-- #100 SUCCESS (Depends Build, Test, Package #401)
|-- #99  SUCCESS (Depends Build, Test, Package #398)
|-- #98  SUCCESS (Depends Build, Test, Package #390)

Deploy to QA
|-- #10 SUCCESS (Depends Deploy to CI #100)
|-- #9  SUCCESS (Depends Deploy to CI #98)
```

And in Octopus I would see the following:

```
Release
|-- 1.0.0.100 CI, QA
|-- 1.0.0.99  CI
|-- 1.0.0.98  CI, QA
```

How can I pass along a specific version number to promote to a given environment in TeamCity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I went into the build steps for the various build configurations, I realized I can reference the properties of dependent build configurations.

For the example above, I have the following configurations and ids:

```
Build, Test, Package - btp1
Deploy to CI - dtc1
Deploy to QA - dtq1
```

In my `Build, Test Package` build configuration I configured my `OctoPack` version number as:

```
%MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%build.vcs.number%.%build.number%
```

Then in the Deploy configurations, I changed the version number to be:

```
Deploy to CI - %MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%dep.btp1.build.vcs.number%.%dep.btp1.build.number%
Deploy to QA - %MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%dep.btp1.build.vcs.number%.%dep.btp1.build.number%
```

By doing so, I was able to reference the build number of the previous builds to promote the correct release from one environment to another.

Comment: Yep, depedencies in TeamCity are the way to go. Thanks for sharing your answer :)